# Hiding the header change the content position and left a white space in the bottom

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am hiding/showing the header dynamically and just noticed, when the header is hidden, that the viewport is shifted to the top by around 40 pixels which is obvious, But the weird behaviour is just now a 40 pixels of white space appears at the bottom of the content, so I need to adjust the content height or update the layout in a sort to tell the content to update it's height.

For this, I already tried several way but they weren't efficient enough to fix the layout issue.

PS: I am not using footer on the page div.

**Method 1:**

```
  $('.ui-header').hide().animate();

  $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
```

**Method 2:**

```
  $('.ui-header').hide().animate();

  $('[data-role=content]').trigger('refresh').trigger('updatelayout');
```

Also, I have tried to calculate the new page height after the header is hidden and assign the new height to the content `$('.ui-content').height(newContentHeight);`

Comment: the header is fixed? can you setup a fiddle to understand the issue more?

Comment: @omar, yes the header is fixed. I am afraid I cannot make a fiddle for this because several third part plugins are involved, so the fiddle will not reproduce the issue exactly like I want.

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/o5nL2pqb/

Comment: Thanks @omar, It's very similar, but it doesn't work. I will update my post after I search more about that :)

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, removed `fullscreen` as I was testing it. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gg82fcxx/

Comment: Sorry for being late replying to you Omar, I fixed the issue by assigning the screen height to the scrolling div: `var screen = $(document).height();
$(".iscroll-wrapper").height(screen);` Thanks for your continuous support :)